# querystring is not being retrieved by .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, google-app-engine, mod-rewrite

I am using PHP in a Google cloud compute engine container. The following `.htaccess` code should retrieve a query string param `g` - but somehow there is no query string parameter that is being retrieved.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options All -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(.sh)/?$ index.php?g=$1 [QSA,L]
```

By way of example:

`http://example.com/dir/dallas.sh` should be able to retrieve `dallas` as the value of query string parameter `g`? But it is not doing that?

The `.htaccess` file with the rewrite code is in the subdirectory `dir` with `index.php` that is looking for the query string parameter `g`.

I have tried to test if `.htaccess` itself is working. I can prevent directory browsing by putting in the code in the `.htaccess` file for the directory:

```
Options -Indexes
```

Thanks @w3dk - this is now working. Mod_rewrite module loads in httpd.conf. I restarted the apache server.  I am able to now retrieve Dallas from the querystring. No idea if I was doing something wrong. No idea if there was something reset by Google Support. Is any one familiar with similar intermittent on-off on querystring retrieval from htaccess in apache on google cloud. They officially DO NOT support htaccess in their app-engine containers or in firebase. Curious. Any way? false alarm. Thanks a lot @w3dk for your responses.

Comment: What is your request URL? Your `Options` directive is invalid, you shouldn't mix -/+ values and bare values.

Comment: Update: I went into the httpd.conf file and changed the Allow override option to Allow All (it was Allow None) and now directory browsing is prevented. Querystring is still not working. Thanks.

Comment: Re: the querystring - url is

Comment: Please see example above - for the url that should be able retrieve the querystring parameter?

Comment: What actually happens when you request `example.com/dir/dallas.sh`? Is it routed? Is mod_rewrite enabled and working?

Comment: "intermittent on-off on querystring retrieval" - this would seem unlikely IMO? (You aren't _retrieving_ the query string; you are simply _setting_ it). Are you sure mod_rewrite was working at all before restarting Apache?

Comment: It appears that you solved the issue, would you mind posting a reply with the answer to help the community, as it's confusing having it all in the question.